# Login form in modal

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a webpage, where I want the ability to log in and see some user stuff.
To log in, you have to click on a link, and then a jQuery modal window, is appearing. My question is now, how to I implement the login form, so the user actually can log in?

Right now, it is only input fields, without any php, since the modal is JavaScript generated.

Should I add the login-PHP on every single pages on my site, or should I add an iframe in the modal, linking to the login.php file, or should I use AJAX to send the username and password to an external site, or something else?

Some one who please can help me? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ajax, send your login info to the sever and get a code for confirmation, if the confirmation code is received, then the close modal and reload the page, here is a code snippet i used for my project once, it worked fine modify it to suite  style

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">

    function action(num) {
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'action_reciver.php',
            data: 'confirm=' + num

        });
    }
</script>
```

this code will send info the action_receiver.php using the post request method. Use the console to debug.

Comment: But is it safe to send the password to the server, without any encryption? :)

Comment: use the post method in the ajax, it as safe as the normal post in an html form